# How to isolate uncertainty in formula involving Around[]?

Tags: error-propagation

If I compute with Mathematica

```
Exp[Around[v, dv]] //PowerExpand
```

I get

```
Around[Exp[v], dv*Exp[v]]
```

with the uncertainty `dv*Exp[v]` separated from the quantity itself.

However, if I make a minimal change and compute

```
Exp[Around[v, dv]/c]
```

Mathematica returns the expression unevaluated instead of returning the proper expression below

```
Around[Exp[v/c], Exp[v/c]*dv/c]
```

Is this a bug or is there a way to force Mathematica to expand the expression involving `Around`? Using `FullSimplify` of `Expand` did not work.

Or is it not possible to mix uncertain and non-uncertain variables in a Mathematica expression?

Comment: Likely `Around` has `TagSetDelayed` with several functions. However, the parser cannot apply the definition when `Around` is not the `Head` of an argument to these functions. `Head[Around[v, dv]/c]` is `Times` but `Head[Around[v, dv]/2]` is `Around`.  So when the head is `Around` in `Exp` the calculation completes.  When it is not it just holds until the head changes, e.g. `Exp[Around[v, dv]/c] /. c -> 2`.

Comment: Note that `Around` is still *Experimental* in version 13.0.1 so this might be something they are working on before the completed release of the function. You can raise the issue with WRI to bring awareness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I received a useful solution from Wolfram Support. I need to specify that my constant is numeric

```
NumericQ[c] ^= True;
Exp[Around[v, dv]/c] // PowerExpand
```

returns the desired answer

```
Around[Exp[v/c], Exp[v/c]*dv/Abs[c]]
```